# why asp.net wont delete my row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to delete a row from my Database,

this is my code :

```
sql = "delete sum_lines from sum_lines join sum_tbl on sum_lines.summary_id = sum_tbl.id where sum_tbl.user_id = @userId and sum_lines.line_id ='@lineId'";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        dataObj = new DataObj();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userId", userId));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lineId", lineId));


        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

the thing is, that if Im trying my sql statement in the management tool , it works perfectly.
but it wont effect on my database when my code is running.

it DOES go to this code, I can see in my debug mode, but it wont effecting for some reason . 
any inputs ?

Comment: are you using `TransactionScope` with this?

Comment: I dont know what is it, so I guess no

Comment: Can you show us a sanitized version of your connection string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove single quotes around `'@lineId'`. With quotes you are specifying the value equal to `@lineid` string in the second condition.

Comment: oh thanks, it worked.  I thought because its a string you have to place single qoutes.   guess not if its in parameters . you've helped. thanks.

Comment: @thormayer - Consider parameters in sql statement as variables. With `com.Parameters.Add` you specify values of those variables.